Sales Rep and commission in netsuite
I am trying to create a customer via NetSuite REST API and assign sales representatives with
their commission percentage. However, I'm facing issues with saving sales
representatives and commission percentages. Here’s the payload I’m using:
https://{accountId}.suitetalk.api.netsuite.com/services/rest/record/v1/customer
Payload:
{
  "companyName": "testcompany",
  "email": "testcompany@yopmail.com",
  "salesTeam": {
    "items": [
      {
        "employee": { 
          "id": "1"
        },
        "salesRole": {
          "id": "-2"
        },
        "isPrimary": true,
        "contribution": 100,
        "commission": 2,
        "custrecord_sales_rep_name": "AAA",
        "custrecord_sales_rep_comm_percentage": "1",
        "split": 50
      }
    ]
  }
}

However, after creating the customer, I don't see the sales representatives or commission
percentages being saved. I have tried using the fields custrecord_sales_rep_name and
custrecord_sales_rep_comm_percentage, but no luck.
Is there a specific field or configuration I need to use for assigning sales representatives
and their commissions in the API request?
